# Why is Json Slurper giving a missing method exception when trying to read from a file?

Tags: json, groovy

I have a file which has some JSON that I want to read that into Groovy so I can parse out some of it's elements....

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

 File jsonFile = new File("/Users/john/Downloads/databaseLATEST.json")
 def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(jsonFile)
```

But this is giving an exception...

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [/Users/john/Downloads/databaseLATEST.json]
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.Reader), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), any(), grep(), wait(long)
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parse(java.io.File)), parse does take java.io.File. So why this error?

Could it be I am using an older version of Groovy (1.8.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The method you seek is only available starting on Groovy 2.2.0, as [mentioned in the docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parse(java.io.File)).

I suggest you always read the docs for the specific version you are using, instead of the latest. That is, for 1.8.6, you [should have been looking here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/1.8.6/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). That shows there's only one method available and it takes a Reader: `parse(Reader reader)`